# Is there any other impact of securities litigation on firms other than the direct cost of litigation and damages?

Tags: untagged

I feel that the impact must exceed the direct costs, but I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: That's a controversial area, with different opinions... A good subject for a Law School discussion, not Quant Finance.

Comment: Even if we build quantitative models to assess costs, you would need to be specific. Costs of regular audited reporting differ from costs of limiting HFT which all differ from costs of requiring margin and so on...